# Web scraper using dart

Tags: html, css, flutter, dart

I am trying to create a web **scraper** for a single website picking out just a title, Image and link to the website.
The title comes out fine but the image and link are not properly working can anyone please help me out in this.Here is my code and dependencies I used in .yaml

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_animations/flutter_staggered_animations.dart';
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> title;
  List<String> image;
  List<String> link;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getdataFromWeb();
  }

  void _getdataFromWeb() async {
    final response = await http.get('https://www.bewakoof.com/men-shirts');
    dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
    final pictures = document.getElementsByClassName('productGrid');
    final description = document.getElementsByClassName('productCardDetail');
    final nextPage =
      //document.getElementsByClassName('entry-title');
      document.getElementsByClassName('col-sm-4 col-xs-6');

    image = pictures
      .map((element) =>
          element.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].attributes['src'])
      .toList();
    title = description
      .map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].innerHtml)
      .toList();
    link = nextPage
      .map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].attributes['href'])
      .toList();
    print(link);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("hello");
    if (image == null)
      print("null");
    else
      print(image);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
      body: title == null || title.length == 0
        ? Text(
            "No data",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          )
        : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: title.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
                position: index,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 375),
                child: SlideAnimation(
                  child: FadeInAnimation(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () async {
                        dynamic url = link[index];
                        if (await canLaunch(url))
                          launch(url);
                        else {
                          print('error');
                        }
                      },
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Card(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.black87,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Text(
                                    title[index],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.cyan,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 15),
                                Image.network(image[0]),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
http: ^0.12.0+4
html: ^0.14.0+3
flutter_staggered_animations: "^0.1.2"
url_launcher: ^5.4.0
```

I may need it tomorrow if it can be possible

Comment: If you aren't scraping the image and link properly then the elements you are looking for don't exist the way you are trying to fetch them. Check the source HTML you are trying to scrape and alter your code to match it.

Comment: FYI it’s __scraper__ (and __scraping__, __scrape__, __scraped__) not scrapper.

Comment: I tried matching it there is no problem in the tags i cross checked them multiple times anything else you can tell me ??please i am desperate:(

Comment: anything useful you can tell me @barny

Comment: It would have helped if you had posted the html that you are scraping or mentioned what "are not properly working" means. Is the string truncated, returned as null, throws an error.... As someone else has suggested, the shape of the html and what you are looking for are probably not the same. Not sure what this is for, but if it were me, i would start by looking at the items one at a time. Find the root element for each product, then find the image, text and whatever else you need inside that element. I am sure they will have some ids. Without the html and the errors, not much else can happen

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToF2R.png)

Here I added the html pic for the elements rest part I debugged only the link is not working.
Here is the debugged code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_animations/flutter_staggered_animations.dart';
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> title;
  List<String> image;
  List<String> link;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getdataFromWeb();
}

      void _getdataFromWeb() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        'https://www.bewakoof.com/');
    dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
    final pictures =
        document.getElementsByClassName('chWrprInner');
    //document.getElementsByClassName('entry-header blog-entry-header');
final description =
    //document.getElementsByClassName('entry-content');
    document.getElementsByClassName('chWrprInner');
final nextPage =
    //document.getElementsByClassName('entry-title');
    document.getElementsByClassName('chWrprInner');

image = pictures
    .map((element) =>
          element.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]
          .attributes['src'])
      .toList();
  title = description
      .map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]
          .innerHtml)
       .toList();
  link = nextPage
      .map((element) =>
          element.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]
          .attributes['href'])
       .toList();
  print(link);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
print("hello");
if (image == null)
  print("null");
else
  print(image);
return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
    body: title == null || title.length == 0
        ? Text(
            "No data",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          )
        : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: title.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
                position: index,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 375),
                child: SlideAnimation(
                    child: FadeInAnimation(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () async {
                    dynamic url = link[index];
                    if (await canLaunch(url))
                      launch(url);
                    else {
                      print('error');
                    }
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Card(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.black87,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(
                                title[index],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.cyan,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 15),
                            Text(
                                 title[index],
                                 style: TextStyle(
                               color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Image.network(image[index]),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ))),
              );
            },
          ),
  ),
);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package for web scraping:

```
  web_scraper: ^0.0.9
```

if need see sample , you can visit this repository:

https://github.com/esmaeil-ahmadipour/Flutter_Web_Scraper